# Forcing Excel to show only whole numbers on a Y axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, axis

I have a chart that is only a Y axis with minimum value of 81.87 and max value of 91.87. Looks like this:

[image: Chart]

I'd like to modify it in such way that only whole numbers are displayed (82, 83, 84 and so on), while keeping the minimum and maximum axis values as they are now - 81.87 and 91.87. Now, I want the numbers to be at their correct place, so in example the 82 should be slightly lower than the current 81.87 mark. I only found a way to show the full numbers in the place of current labels, which in my case just isn't sufficient.

I found a workaround for this - I could add a new series with Y values of my desired labels and X values of 0, plot them, change the markers to lines and add data labels. This way would get me the result I need, however I was hoping to find a more "elegant" solution. Let me know if you have any ideas!

Comment: What type of chart do you have? Can you post also some sample data? Which version of Excel? I can' replicate your issue.

Comment: The chart type is XY scatter, however if this can be done with any other chart type, I don't mind changing it. I don't have any sample data as this "chart" is just the Y axis, the rest is removed. The intent is to use it as a depth measurement on a borehole log.

Comment: You can read this article:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/change-the-display-of-chart-axes-422c97af-1483-4bad-a3db-3a9ef630b5a9

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your issue, but for me it already works as your desired way.

To fix your chart, please follow these steps:

- right click axis and select "format axis"
- in Axis options make sure "minimum" bound and "major" units are integers

[image]

Comment: Thanks Máté, although this does not solve my problem, because I need the minimum and maximum axis value to stay as they currently are - so 81.87 and 91.87.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to control range and labels separately.

Comment: @Pawel Dare I ask why you need such a specific axis range?

Comment: It's for a borehole log. Basically there will be 2 axes like this, one going from 0 to 10 or 20 always, presenting the depth of drill penetration, so that's easy. But the second one is always going from the elevation, so if the ground is at say -81.57 (it's at sea) the axis needs to go from that value to 10/20 meters deeper.

Comment: You can set your axis cross where you need, that might help